# Bound of the spinor element in Seiberg-Witten equation for a Kähler surface

Tags: riemannian-geometry, 4-manifolds, spin-geometry

Let's say we want to solve a perturbed version of SW equations on a closed Kähler manifold $(X,\omega):$
\begin{align*}
&D_A\phi=0\\
&F_A+it\omega=q(\phi)=\phi\otimes\phi^*-\frac{|\phi|^2}{2}\text{Id}
\end{align*}
for $t>0.$ I take $\phi=(c,0)\in\Omega^0(X;\mathbb{C})\oplus \Omega^{0,2}(X;\mathbb{C}),$ for some positive constant $c.$ This solves the Dirac equation: $\bar\partial c=0.$ The curvature equations would turn into:
\begin{align*}
F_A^++it\omega=\frac{i}{4}c^2\omega, F_A^{0,2}=0.
\end{align*}
To solve this we change the natural hermitian metric on the determinant line bundle by $e^\lambda,$ for some smooth real valued function $\lambda.$ The new curvature turns into:
\begin{align*}
F_{A'}=F_A-\partial\bar\partial(\lambda)
\end{align*}
So we need to solve for:
\begin{align*}
&F_A^+-(\partial\bar\partial(\lambda))^+=\frac{i}{4}(e^\lambda c^2-4t)\omega\\
&\text{or equivalently},\\
&\langle F_A,\omega\rangle-\langle\partial\bar\partial(\lambda),\omega\rangle=\frac{i}{2}(e^\lambda c^2-4t)\\
&\Leftrightarrow 0-\frac{i}{2}\Delta\lambda=\frac{i}{2}(e^\lambda c^2-4t)\hspace{2 ex}\text{(the Chern connection induced from the canonical metric on $\mathbb{C}$, A is flat)}\\
&\Leftrightarrow\Delta\lambda+e^\lambda c^2=4t
\end{align*}
The above can be solved for $\lambda,$ when $t$ is positive using Kadzan-Warner's work.

Now this gives me an impression that the spinor isn't really bounded unless we look at the gauge equivalence, as we can take any constant in $\mathbb{C},$ and secondly the norm of the spinor doesn't depend on $t.$ $t$ is solely used to find the metric. But the usual maximal principal argument gives a bound on the norm of the spinor in terms of the scalar curvature of the manifold. Where am I going wrong here? Also, in symplectic case some analysis shows the norm of the spinor to be dependent on $t$. See [here](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/swnotes.pdf#page=289). Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that you need to understand what's the meaning of $\lambda$ be a solution. (See Proposition 3.2.7 in the book you post.) In your case, fixing a Hermitian metric $h_0$, $e^{\lambda}=-\frac{4t}{c^2}$ is a solution to the Kadzan-Warner equation and $h_0e^{\lambda}$ will be a new hermitian metric. However, if we want the connection to be unitary w.r.t. $h_0$, and $\phi$ still satisfies the SW equations for the unitary connection, we need to use gauge transformation g=e^{\frac{\lambda}{2}}(which is not unitary).

Comment: In this case, the spinor will be $g\phi=(-2\sqrt{t},0)$. For different $c$, you get the same solution.

Comment: @SiqiHe thanks for the comment, would you please elaborate what exactly is meant by "connection to be unitary w.r.t. $h_0$"?

Comment: In the case you considered, the connection $A$ should be compatible with the Hermitian metric. Connection $A$ is unitary means $\partial\langle s_1,s_2 \rangle=\langle \bar{\partial}_A s_1, s_2\rangle+\langle s_1,\partial_A s_2\rangle$. Given a Riemnnian metric $h$ and given a holomorphic structure, the $\bar{\partial}_A$ will determinant what is $d_A$.